# How to display line chart in a view?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I want line chart in my application can any one tell me how can we make line chart & display it in view.& which frame work is needed for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean a graph done with lines showing relationships between coordinates?

If so, Quartz drawing might be easiest. The framework is CoreGraphics. You get a reference to the CGContext, tell it where the line starts (moveToPoint, x, y) and ends (addLineToPoint, x, y), and stroke the path.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Core-plot.

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/